# How to bake HDRI into sphere?

Tags: baking, hdri

I'd like to bake HDRI lighting to a sphere object, then with the emission shader I'd like to use it as light source. Is it possible to bake HDRI map to a sphere object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you ask, if you're talking about projecting an HDRI image onto a shpere, you don't need to bake anything, the default UV sphere unwrap will correctly project an HDRI image onto it:

[image]

If you're talking about baking a 3D scene onto an HDRI image it is another question, put your camera at the center of the scene, go into the *Camera* panel and choose *Lens > Panoramic*, *Type > Equirectangular*, in the *Output* panel choose the dimension (the length must be twice the height), render, save as *Radiance HDR* format. If you want to project it onto a UV sphere, just plug the HDRI into the *Emission* node as explained before.

Comment: Sorry that I've made things complicated. I was just asking this. Thank you!